# How to test for null keys on any Java map implementation?

Tags: java, collections

I would like to ensure that a Map being passed as an argument to a method doesn't include null keys. One would assume that the following would do:

```
if ( map.containsKey(null) ) …
```

but that will break if the method is passed something like a `TreeMap`, which per the general Java Map contract is [free to reject null keys with a NPE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-).

Do we have a sensible way to test for null keys while accepting any Map implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
boolean hasAnyNull = yourMap.keySet()
      .stream()
      .anyMatch(Objects::isNull);
```

Comment: This may have to loop over all keys, which is usually exactly what you want to avoid when you use a `Map`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer exactly right, but looping over a map might be cheaper than building an `Exception` with the entire stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean hasNullKey(Map<?,?> map) {
  try {
    return map.containsKey(null);
  } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Note that this also returns `false` when `map` itself is `null`, which may or may not be desired.

Comment: System.out.println(hasNullKey(null)); this statement also print false.

Comment: @JoachimSauer exception to control flow... I don't know, not for my taste

Comment: @gifpif: Yes, which is exactly what my note says.

Comment: @Eugene: it's not nice, but it's not O(n). I think the question itself already contains problematic assumptions Why is the presence of a `null` key relevant, yet the code accepts maps that can't have `null` keys? Seems like something that needs to be fixed with a more stringent specification.

Comment: @JoachimSauer the method is part of a library public API: I have no control on the actual implementation of the Map being passed as argument, yet I want to make sure keys are not null

Comment: @A'B: then why don't you do what `containsKey` does? Define your method to (potentially) throw an NPE when the map contains `null` (or if the `Map` *doesn't* accept `null`, depending on which way around you want to handle it).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I'm indeed doing that, but the potentially offending processes are some steps away from the public API call: I'm just trying to trap the issue as soon as possible in order to provide clearer error messages and I was hoping for a one-liner ;-)

Comment: @A'B: ok, so *what* exactly is the "error condition" here? `null` in the map or a map implementation that doesn't allow ` null`? If it's the former, you could run your code, catch the inevitable exception and *then* run some (potentially costly) checks to see if it the exception is caused by a known problem such as passing a broken parameter to your code and provide an appropriate error message.

Comment: @JoachimSauer `null` in the map. Nice hint…

Answer (score 0):

Use `instanceof` to find its a TreeMap

```
boolean hasNullKey(Map<?,?> map) {
    return map instanceof TreeMap ? false :map.containsKey(null);
}
```

Comment: JavaDoc [TreeMap.put](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#put(K,V)) says: "_... throws NullPointerException - if the specified key is null and this map uses natural ordering, or its comparator does not permit null keys_" - A `TreeMap` may contain null-keys if it's comparator can handle them.

Comment: @LuCio *generally* every `Map` since `HashMap` prohibits nulls; this is the case for `CHM/Map::of` etc; having that null is just a pain the soft side

Comment: And what about other maps which do not permit `null` like `EnumMap`?