# EnumSet.spliterator without characteristic Spliterator.NONNULL

Tags: java, java-8, set, spliterator

I was thinking about an answer to the question: [How to test for null keys on any Java map implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52275537/how-to-test-for-null-keys-on-any-java-map-implementation)

My first thought was to check if the `Spliterator` of the keyset of a map has the characteristic `Spliterator.NONNULL`:

```
map.keySet().spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.NONNULL)
```

The [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#NONNULL) says:

> Characteristic value signifying that the source guarantees that
>   encountered elements will not be null. (This applies, for example, to
>   most concurrent collections, queues, and maps.)

Before answering I did some checks:

The  `Spliterator` of a`TreeMap` without a provided `Compararator` does not have this characteristic even though the *natural ordering* does not allow null-keys.

```
new TreeMap<>().keySet().spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.NONNULL); // false
```

Even more suprising was the fact that `Spliterator`s of an `EnumMap` keyset and of `EnumSet` itself do not have this characteristic.

```
EnumSet.allOf(DayOfWeek.class).spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.NONNULL); // false
```

I understand that the result of `spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.NONNULL)` in the above cases returns `false` as the default implementation of `Set.spliterator()` is evaluated.

But is there a reason why the spliterators of these sets do not override `Set.spliterator()` to create a `Spliterator` with `Spliterator.NONNULL`? Would this break a specification I am not aware of?

Comment: Although a `TreeMap` relying on its elements' natural ordering cannot accommodate null keys, one based on a suitable `Comparator` can do.  Thus, whether null keys are accepted is not a characteristic of the `TreeMap` class itself, and is not reflected in its key set's `Spliterator`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Right - therefore I described the case of _natural ordering_.  `keySet().spliterator()` of `TreeMap` could check if a comparator is set as the `TreeMap` does in other places.

Comment: It *could do*, @LuCio, but it does not.  My point is that this is a property deriving from the `TreeMap` *class*, not an instance-specific property.  This is what I would expect anyway, but it is in fact documented.  Pursuant to the docs for `Set.spliterator()`, which specify that implementations should report characteristics other than `Spliterator.DISTINCT` that they provide, `TreeMap.keySet()` declares the characteristics that key sets provide, and they do not include `Spliterator.NONNULL`, not even conditionally.  Thus, you should not expect these spliterators to have that characteristic.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ok ... in case of `TreeMap` that might be quite understandable. And it wasn't that suprising as for `EnumMap`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am a little bit confused by your last comment. `TreeMap` *could* implement a specific `keySet` method that would return a specific `Set` that reports that `NONNULL`. Are you saying no way this can happen? Sorry, I might just be confused here

Comment: @Eugene, I have expanded my comments into an answer, which I hope is clearer on that topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even worse:

```
System.out.println(Set.of(1)
             .spliterator()
             .hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.NONNULL)); // false
```

Even if those `Set::of` methods are documented as:

> throws NullPointerException if the element is null

So there is no way to end up with a null in that `Set`. I guess the real answer is that this is *not yet done*.

**EDIT**

See the [comment from Stuart Marks about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352920/immutablecollections-setn-implementation-detail/45361246#comment77731969_45361246)

Comment: Yes .. _not done yet_ is something I could imagine too. Thus there is the possibility it will be done.

Comment: But you can create an `EnumSet` with `EnumSet.copyOf(Collections.singletonList(null))`, it will contain a `null` then... or am I missing something? EDIT: `Set`s Javadoc states "contain no pair of elements [...] and at most one null element`. So why would its spliterator guarantee non-null?

Comment: He says: "_all of these are implementation specifics and may change from one release to the next,_". Thus this implementation detail too.

Comment: @LuCio well, if `Set::of` is documented to throw an exception on nulls, this will not change. my point was that he says this specific `spliterator` methods are not yet done

Comment: …and [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46649315/2711488), the current Stream implementation doesn’t utilize the `NONNULL` characteristic, so the JRE maintainers feel no urge to implement reporting it where feasible. Though, in my opinion, it would be really useful for the `Set.of(…)` variants to report it, to allow simple checking, as `contains(null)` will throw an NPE, so the only alternative is a linear loop (to be done whenever we suspect that a collection *could* be a `Set.of(…)`)…

Comment: @Holger Thx for the link. It makes clear it's not only about `NONNULL`. There is a greater gap.

Comment: @daniu the contract of `Set` allows implementations supporting `null`, but does not require it. So `EnumSet` is an implementation which does not support `null` and `EnumSet.copyOf(Collections.singletonList(null))` does not even compile, as there is no actual `enum` type to infer. If you provide a type, it will throw a `NullPointerException` at runtime. By the way, since `EnumSet.copyOf` must be able to determine the actual `enum` type at runtime, the source collection must contain at least one actual constant (unless the source itself is an `EnumSet` too).

Comment: @Holger I see. I did cut the code down (from two lines which compiled) so it would fit into a comment properly, but didn't actually run it.

Answer (score 3):

> But is there a reason why the spliterators of these sets do not override `Set.spliterator()` to create a `Spliterator` with `Spliterator.NONNULL`?

We can only speculate, but certainly it is the case that some `TreeMap` instances that use `Comparator`s for ordering do accommodate null keys, and therefore their key sets' spliterators must not have characteristic `Spliterator.NONNULL`.  Although it is true that a `TreeMap` that uses its keys' natural ordering cannot accommodate null keys, I do not personally find it surprising that `TreeMap`'s key sets do not use that to make a distinction.  This is the kind of property that I would expect to be driven exclusively by the classes involved, not by per-instance details.

> Would this break a specification I am not aware of?

Perhaps.  [The docs for `Set.spliterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#spliterator()) specify

> The `Spliterator` reports `Spliterator.DISTINCT`. **Implementations should document the reporting of additional characteristic values.**

(Emphasis added.)  [The docs for TreeMap.keySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#keySet()) say

> The set's spliterator is *late-binding*, *fail-fast*, and additionally
>   reports `Spliterator.SORTED` and `Spliterator.ORDERED` with an encounter
>   order that is ascending key order. The spliterator's comparator (see
>   `Spliterator.getComparator()`) is `null` if the tree map's comparator (see
>   `SortedMap.comparator()`) is `null`. Otherwise, the spliterator's
>   comparator is the same as or imposes the same total ordering as the
>   tree map's comparator.

Note well that the docs for this set comply with the expectation set in the `Set.spliterator()` docs without designating, even conditionally, that `Spliterator.NONNULL` is among the characteristics that key sets' spliterators will report.  Note further that those same docs *do* describe other characteristics of those sets that vary depending on whether the map's order is based on a comparator.

Thus, no, you should not expect `TreeMap` key sets', spliterators to have report `Spliterator.NONNULL` under any circumstances.  I cannot definitively speak to why this choice was made, but it is consistent with my perception of Java design philosophy.

You also wrote,

> Even more suprising was the fact that `Spliterator`s of an `EnumMap`
>   keyset and of `EnumSet` itself do not have this characteristic.

I agree that these spliterators could reasonably report `Spliterator.NONNULL`.  I do not know why the choice was made that they would not do so, unless it was simply an oversight.  Nevertheless, I observe that their docs indeed do not specify that these spliterators will report `Spliterator.NONNULL`.  With that being the case, it is to be expected that those spliterators will not report that characteristic.

Comment: I understand. But I don't see a possible violation of the specification. The docs of `TreeMap.keySet()` don't mention `Spliterator.NONNULL` and the docs of `EnumMap.keySet()` don't do it too. IMO this doesn't mean, other characterisitcs are excluded. The docs are saying what the code actually does. If other characterisitcs will come, they will have to be documented too.

Comment: @LuCio, that undocumented characteristics are excluded is *exactly* how I read the provision of the `Set.spliterator()` docs that I presented.  Or if you think "excluded" is too strong, then at minimum I fully expect the spliterators provided by the standard library itself to comply with the "should" clause in the docs of `Set.spliterator()`, so that the absence of any documentation of them reporting `Spliterator.NONNULL` is, for them, a reliable indication that indeed they will not report that characteristic.

Comment: By _excluded_ I wanted to say they aren't _excluded to come_ regarding @Eugene answer. As of now they are _excluded to be reported_ as they aren't documented and all reported characteristics have to be documented. So you're right: this excludes them. Thus I can't expect `Spliterator.NONNULL` to be set, +1